# convert json to multi level array

Tags: php, json

convert REST response in JSON to PHP arrray

Set the following up but got error =

> Trying to get property of non-object in C:......

our JSON looks like

```
{
    "craneIDs": [{
        "craneID": "R01"
    }, {
        "craneID": "R02"
    }, {
        "craneID": "R04"
    }, {
        "craneID": "R08"
    }, {
        "craneID": "R09"
    }, {
        "craneID": "R10"
    }, {
        "craneID": "R16"
    }, {
        "craneID": "TC01"
    }, {
        "craneID": "T06"
    }, {
        "craneID": "T08"
    }, {
        "craneID": "T08/2"
    }, {
        "craneID": "T12"
    }]
}
```

after

```
$craneids_url   = 'http://...........';
$craneids_json  = file_get_contents($craneids_url);
$craneids_array = json_decode($craneids_json, true);
$i              = 0;
/* Error on following line */
while ($craneids_array->{'craneIDs'}[$i]) {
    print_r($craneids_array->{'craneIDs'}[$i]->{'craneID'});
    echo "<br />";
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: used foreach loop instead while loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly write without string,

```
// true return raw array but your syntax is for object
$craneids_array = json_decode($craneids_json);
$i =0;
// run while until there is value for craneIDs
while (isset($craneids_array->craneIDs[$i])) {
    print_r($craneids_array->craneIDs[$i]->craneID);
    echo "<br />";
    $i++;
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/qNHfJ)

**Output:-**

```html
R01<br />R02<br />R04<br />R08<br />R09<br />R10<br />R16<br />TC01<br />T06<br />T08<br />T08/2<br />T12<br />
```

Answer (score 0):

With `json_decode($craneids_json, true);` you get an array.

Try:

```
foreach ($craneids_array['craneIDs'] as $craneIDs) {
        print_r($craneIDs['craneID']);
        echo "<br />";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code you provided is that *craneIDs* is not a property of the object returned by json_decode, but it is a key. The following works:

```
//Replace $craneids_array->{'craneIDs'} with $craneids_array['craneIDs']

while ($craneids_array['craneIDs'][$i]) { 
    print_r($craneids_array['craneIDs'][$i]['craneID']);
    echo "<br />";
    $i++;
}
```

Working example [here](https://ideone.com/lUqam5)